# Alternative to mediacore in PHP?

Tags: web-development, video

What's a good (also free) alternative to mediacore (http://getmediacore.com/) but done in PHP.

I mean with the same good look&feel, support and community support.

Comment: Interestingly, MediaCore apparently [started out as PHP](http://getmediacore.com/community/topic/deploying-mediacore-final-hurdle#post-770). Initial searching for a fork(just in case) isn't turning anything up yet, though. Good luck with this one; I'm interested now, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found PHP Melody that might serve as a substitute. [PHP Melody](http://www.phpsugar.com/phpmelody.html) has the following features:

- Private Videos
- SEO Friendly
- Mass Video Import
- JW Player / FlowPlayer
- Multiple video sources Optimized for speed
- UTF-8 Support
- Built-in Article
- Manager The ability to embed any video from any source
- Upload your own videos
- Video-checking bot
- Security

Granted, it isn't as advanced as MediaCore, but it has a lot of the same features and can probably do most of the things MediaCore can.

Comment: It looks good, I'll check it out. It just doesn't match mediacore because it's not free. I'll wait for more answers to see if something free comes up.